# bladesystem c7000 power supply error

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit, blade-chassis

I have a hp blade system c7000 with six power supply connected. it turns on with critical error in power supply #1,2,5 and I can't see the power supply 1,4,6 in onboard administrator interface. I updated firmware to resolve the problem but I saw the error again. I replaced the power supplies but nothing happened. what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should follow HP's advice and instructions. 
There is a diagnostic code in your screenshot.

It says to replace the power supply per [HP advisory c01519680](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01519680).

*Have you done this?*

[image]

> RESOLUTION HP has provided updated HP Onboard Administrator Firmware
>   (Version 3.11 or later) to enable customers to identify potentially
>   affected power supplies. Power Supplies identified by the OA should be
>   replaced immediately by contacting HP Customer Support and request
>   Spares Kit 411099-001. The Spares Kit will be dispatched at no charge
>   to the customer.
>
> In North America, contact Customer Support at 1-800-334-5144.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have followed this advice but Actually I see this error even if I remove the power supply or replaced it with other power supplies!